# Joomla! Too Many Redirects

Tags: redirect, joomla

I'm trying to build a website (it's not my first time), using latest version of Joomla! (3.8.10), but I have a problem - tabs in the main menu don't work. When I try to go to other page, I have an error:

```
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I almost solved this problem by changing:

```
$sef="1"
```

to

```
$sef="0"
```

in `configuration.php`, but it caused strangely long addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Need to add:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

in `index.php`file, behind the `<?php`

Maybe someone will use it.

Comment: This was the only thing that solved my issue, thank you, I would never get this solution.

Comment: Yes, thank you !  Also the sme thing for /administrator/index.php

Comment: This worked for me as well on joomla 4.x. I have never faced this problem before, where setting "Force HTTPS" breaks the site. This solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a problem with your .htaccess file. 
 When you change $sef=0, you are basically telling the system to not use your .htaccess file. 
 I suggest backing up your current one and replacing with the default Joomla one.  It is the one that comes in the download package and is named htaccess.txt.  Upload and rename to .htaccess to overwrite existing.

Comment: I did as you suggest, unfortunately did not help. Problem still exist.